# how strong consistency and eventual consistency work in datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

i'm no expert in Databases so what i know about queries is that they are the way to read or write  in databases

in eventual consistency read will return stale data

in write query first data node will be updated but other node will need some time to be updated

in strong consistency read will be locked until data get modified to it latest version (really i'm not sure about what i said here so help if u got it wrong)

in write query all read operations for will be lock until data node get modified to its latest version

so if i write data as eventual and tried ancestors query to get that data will i get the latest version ?

if i used ancestors query to update would all eventual read operation get the latest version ?

update

i think Transactions is there so if there is  multi modification request to the same data 1 will succeeded and other will fail after that the data the have been modified will take some time to be replicated in all datacenter so if transaction succeeded  does not mean all read query will return the latest version (correct me if i'm right)

Comment: plz answer my questions and start with yes or no so i can understand

Answer (score 1):

If you use what you call an "ancestor query", you're working in a *transaction*: either the transaction terminates successfully, in which case all subsequent reads will get the values as updated by the transaction, or else the transaction fails, in which case none of the changes made by the transaction will be seen (this all-or-nothing property is often referred to as a transaction being "atomic"). In particular, you do get strong consistency this way, not just eventual consistency.

The cost can be large, in terms of performance and scalability. In particular, an application should not update an entity group (any and all entities descending from a common ancestor) more than once a second, which can be a very constraining limit for a highly scalable application.

The online docs include a large variety of tips, tricks and advice on how to deal with this -- you could start at https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/ and continue with the "additional resources" this article lists at the end.

One simple idea that often suffices is that (differently from queries) getting a specific entity from its key *is* strongly consistent without needing transactions, and `memcache` is also strongly consistent; writing a modified entity gives you its new key, so you can stash that key into memcache and have other parts of your code fetch the modified entity from that key, rather than relying on queries. This has limits, of course, because `memcache` doesn't give you unbounded space -- but it's a useful idea to keep in mind, nevertheless, in many practical cases.

Answer (score -1):

With GAE the only way to be consistante is to use transaction, into a transaction you can update, query the last update but it's slower.
For me using ancestors just compose the primary key and that's all.

Comment: This is not true. `get` operations and ancestor queries are always strongly  consistent.

Comment: can you plz answer my questions i know about transactions that they are the way that ancestors query use to provide atomic property to datastore